# SSH Login With Password

Tags: ssh

I created a vsp (specifically, a "droplet" on digitalocean) and can login as root with no problem:

```
ssh -i mykey root@111.11.111.11
```

While root, I created a new user, then granted them sudo access:

```
adduser newuser
usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

For that new user, I want to be able to login using a password. However, the following gives me **Permission denied (publickey)**:

```
ssh newuser@111.11.111.11
```

Shouldn't I be able to login using a password by default instead of using an ssh key? Or is there some way to specify I want to login that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for this line `PasswordAuthentication yes` in your your `sshd_config` file.

What you could also do is to only allow `newuser` to use password by using:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
Match User your-user
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. The strange thing, though, is that if i use the digitalocean console I am able to login with password. Maybe that ignores the sshd_config?

Comment: This works! But apparently only after I then restart the ssh service (sudo service ssh restart) OR the sshd service.